# Http (fetch-XHR) requests are being canceled some time. i m using Flutter Web (get: ^4.6.6) + Xampp(Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, flutter, http, xampp

[image]

[image]

Http (fetch-XHR)  request goes canceled state and sometimes it's working.

Most Probably it's not working at first time after the page loads.

Once I do a hard refresh then it's working.

below is my flutter code

**api_client.dart** class

```
class ApiClient extends GetConnect {
  String getAuthorizationToken() {
    final String token = 'Bearer ${getToken()}';
    //debugPrint("token $token");
    return token;
  }
  String getToken() {
    return "Example Token";
  }
}
```

**BidProvider.dart file**

```
class BidProvider extends ApiClient {
  @override
  void onInit() {
    httpClient.addRequestModifier<Object?>((Request<Object?> request) {
      request.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
      request.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
      return request;
    });
    super.onInit();
  }

    Future<Response<ResponseDataArrayModel<BidItem>>> getListForUser({
    required String baseUrl,
    String? queryParams,
  }) async {
    httpClient.defaultDecoder = (val) {
      printJasonString(val as Map<dynamic, dynamic>);
      return ResponseDataArrayModel<BidItem>.fromJson(
          BidItem.empty, val as Map<String, dynamic>);
    };
    httpClient.addRequestModifier<Object?>((Request<Object?> request) {
      request.headers['Accept'] = 'application/json';
      request.headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*';
      request.headers['Authorization'] = super.getAuthorizationToken();
      request.headers['Accept-Language'] = super.getLocal();
      printJasonString(request.headers);
      return request;
    });
    String url = '$baseUrl${ServiceUrl.bid}';
    if (queryParams != null) {
      url = '$url$queryParams';
    }
    //debugPrint('url $url');
    //await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3));
    return httpClient.get<ResponseDataArrayModel<BidItem>>(url);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved after increasing timeout and maxAuthRetries

```
httpClient.timeout = const Duration(seconds: 30);
httpClient.maxAuthRetries = 5;
```

and also check server-side timeout and Keep-Alive it's should be.

[image]

You may set it according to your requirements.